# 0x80070005 - Access is denied when trying to access iframe DOM elements

Tags: dom, com, autohotkey

When I try to access contentWindow.document of an iframe element, I get the error, `0x80070005 - Access is denied.`.

Is it not possible to access elements of iframe document?

**Files:**

- iframe.html
- iframe_test.ahk

**iframe.html**

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <iframe width="100%" height="100%" name="myframe" src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

**iframe_test.ahk**

```
Gui, New, Resize MaximizeBox
Gui, Add, ActiveX, vWB w780 h580, % A_ScriptDir "\iframe.html" 
Gui, show, w800 h600
Loop
   Sleep 10
Until (WB.readyState=4 && WB.document.readyState="complete" && !WB.busy)        
msgbox % WB.document.All["myframe"].contentwindow.document.documentElement.innerHTML
```

Comment: It is possible. However there are cross domain restrictions when doing so. If you're trying to access content on the w3schools website via an iframe that won't work, as your domain does not have permission.

Comment: In other words, it's not possible from a local file. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Often times these errors happen due to the Same-origin policy.

You'll typically be better off relying on something like [`Window.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) or composing a user script to bypass the Same-origin policy.